# Win32 API GetMenuItemInfo returns only the first character of the item text

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

I'm trying to gather the text of a menu item using GetMenuItemInfo API.

This is the code I'm using:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool GetMenuItemInfo(IntPtr hMenu, uint uItem, bool fByPosition, ref MENUITEMINFO lpmii);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MENUITEMINFO 
{
    public uint cbSize;
    public uint fMask;
    public uint fType;
    public uint fState;
    public uint wID;
    public IntPtr hSubMenu;
    public IntPtr hbmpChecked;
    public IntPtr hbmpUnchecked;
    public IntPtr dwItemData;
    public String dwTypeData;
    public uint cch;
    public IntPtr hbmpItem;

    // Return the size of the structure
    public static uint sizeOf
    {
        get { return (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MENUITEMINFO)); }
    }
}

MENUITEMINFO mif = new MENUITEMINFO();
mif.cbSize = MENUITEMINFO.sizeOf;
mif.fMask = MIIM_STRING; 
mif.fType = MFT_STRING;
mif.dwTypeData = null;
bool res = Win32.GetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, (uint)0, true, ref mif); //To load cch into memory

mif.cch += 1;
mif.fMask = MIIM_STRING;
mif.fType = MFT_STRING;
mif.dwTypeData = new String(' ', (Int32)(mif.cch));

res = Win32.GetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, (uint)i, true, ref mif); //To fill dwTypeData
```

Unfortunately after those lines dwTypeData results a string with only 1 character instead of mif.cch characters. Note: this character is the first one of the menu item!

It seems that there's some misalignment in the marshaling of data when returning MENUITEMINFO structure, isn.t it?

Please let me know how to solve such issue!

Best

cghersi

Comment: Maybe because mif.cch += 1; is only one character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your header translation is pretty good, but you've not got `dwTypeData` quite right. That cannot be marshalled from caller to callee using `string`. You need to do that with manual marshalling like this.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool GetMenuItemInfo(IntPtr hMenu, int uItem, bool fByPosition, MENUITEMINFO lpmii);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class MENUITEMINFO 
{
    public int cbSize;
    public uint fMask;
    public uint fType;
    public uint fState;
    public uint wID;
    public IntPtr hSubMenu;
    public IntPtr hbmpChecked;
    public IntPtr hbmpUnchecked;
    public IntPtr dwItemData;
    public IntPtr dwTypeData;
    public uint cch;
    public IntPtr hbmpItem;

    public MENUITEMINFO()
    {
        cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MENUITEMINFO));
    }
}

....

MENUITEMINFO mif = new MENUITEMINFO();
mif.fMask = MIIM_STRING; 
mif.fType = MFT_STRING;

mif.dwTypeData = IntPtr.Zero;
bool res = GetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, 0, true, mif);
if (!res)
    throw new Win32Exception();
mif.cch++;
mif.dwTypeData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((IntPtr)(mif.cch*2));
try
{
    res = GetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, 0, true, mif);
    if (!res)
        throw new Win32Exception();
    string caption = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(mif.dwTypeData);
}
finally
{
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(mif.dwTypeData);
}
```

Comment: Is missing one character, you forgot to increment cch: mif.cch += 1

Comment: Thank you @DavidHeffernan, your solution is woking and seems more adherent to MSDN docs!

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2**

Code found in `System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem` using reflection. Seems that they use string also.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public class MENUITEMINFO_T
{
    public int cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(NativeMethods.MENUITEMINFO_T));
    public int fMask;
    public int fType;
    public int fState;
    public int wID;
    public IntPtr hSubMenu;
    public IntPtr hbmpChecked;
    public IntPtr hbmpUnchecked;
    public IntPtr dwItemData;
    public string dwTypeData;
    public int cch;
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool GetMenuItemInfo(HandleRef hMenu, int uItem, bool fByPosition, [In, Out] MENUITEMINFO_T lpmii);

  ................

  MENUITEMINFO_T menuiteminfo_t;
  menuiteminfo_t = new MENUITEMINFO_T();
  menuiteminfo_t.fMask = MIIM_STRING;
  menuiteminfo_t.dwTypeData = new string('\0', 256);
  menuiteminfo_t.cch = menuiteminfo_t.dwTypeData.Length - 1;
  bool result = GetMenuItemInfo(new HandleRef(null, hMenu), 0, true, menuiteminfo_t);
```

**Update 1**

As @Remy Lebeau suggested, there was a differences between String marshaling vs char[] marshaling.  After I added `CharSet=CharSet.Auto` attribute to the structure everything was working fine using your code.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct MENUITEMINFO
    {
        public uint cbSize;
        public uint fMask;
        public uint fType;
        public uint fState;
        public uint wID;
        public IntPtr hSubMenu;
        public IntPtr hbmpChecked;
        public IntPtr hbmpUnchecked;
        public IntPtr dwItemData;
        public string dwTypeData;
        public uint cch;
        public IntPtr hbmpItem;

        // return the size of the structure
        public static uint sizeOf
        {
            get { return (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MENUITEMINFO)); }
        }
    }


        IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, "untitled - notepad");
        IntPtr hMenu = GetMenu(hWnd);


        MENUITEMINFO mif = new MENUITEMINFO();
        uint MIIM_STRING = 0x00000040;
        uint MFT_STRING = 0x00000000;
        mif.cbSize = MENUITEMINFO.sizeOf;//(uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MENUITEMINFO));
        mif.fMask = MIIM_STRING;
        mif.fType = MFT_STRING;
        mif.dwTypeData = null;
        //IntPtr hMenu = menuStrip1.Handle;



        //1st call to get the text length into (cch)
        bool res = GetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, (uint)0, true, ref mif); //To load cch into memory
        if (res)
        {
            mif.cch += 1;
            //Set the length of the buffer to cch + 1
            mif.dwTypeData = new string(' ', (int)(mif.cch));
            res = GetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, (uint)0, true, ref mif); //To fill dwTypeData

        }
```

Check this link for more details about [Default Marshaling for Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

OLD:

You need to initialize dwTypeData and cch data members.

Get Menu items string example (working with the new MENUITEMINFO structure):

```
List<string> ls = new List<string>();
IntPtr hMenu = Win32.GetMenu(hWnd);

if (hMenu.ToInt32() != 0)
{
    for (int i = Win32.GetMenuItemCount(hMenu); i >= 0; i--)
    {
        uint MIIM_STRING = 0x00000040;
        uint MFT_STRING  = 0x00000000;
        Win32.MENUITEMINFO mif = new Win32.MENUITEMINFO();
        mif.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Win32.MENUITEMINFO));
        mif.fMask = MIIM_STRING;
        mif.fType = MFT_STRING;
        mif.cch = 256;
        mif.dwTypeData = new string(' ', (int)(mif.cch));

        bool a = Win32.GetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, 0, true, ref mif);
        ls.Add(mif.dwTypeData);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647578.aspx), it specifically states that Cristiano's approach is the correct approach when retrieving the menu item's text.  I suspect the issue is related to differences between `String` marshaling vs `char[]` marshaling.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, yes you are right, I was in a hurry and didn't test it. I just did something like this in C++ and I put it as I remembered. This one is tested and working as expected.

Comment: No this does now work. You cannot marshal a string from from caller to callee using `string`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan , I just tested and is working fine like this. I find this solution using reflection to check how the MenuItem is implemented.

Comment: It's wrong. If it works it only does so by chance. You got lucky. It will break at some point. I repeat. You cannot use string to marshal data from callee to caller.

Comment: @Remy No you cannot. Not in a struct. You have to do it the way I say.

Comment: Thank you @MihaiHantea: your solution is working, but I prefer the one of David cause it is more adherent to MSDN stuff. Thank you very much to everybody!